# Create Migration from worker service project

Tags: service, frameworks, migration, entity, worker

My DbContext is in a separate class library project.

I want to generate migration using a worker service project.

is it possible?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Used this method and try again to generate migration. Maybe it will work well for you:

```js
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    => Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices(
            (hostContext, services) =>
            {
             var connectionString = hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");

                     var migrationAssemblyName = typeof(Worker).Assembly.FullName;

                    services.AddDbContext<StockDbContext>(option => 
                    option.UseSqlServer(connectionString, 
                        b => b.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)));
            });
```

Comment: Check this link maybe gets you solution

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli

Comment: This video also help you...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AElJVCIABdQ